# Can you call a different version of jQuery just to use for a script?

Tags: jquery

If a site you're editing using one version of jQuery, and upgrading breaks a lot, and a new script you're working on needs a newer version, is there a way to call and use the newer jQuery within that script such that it doesn't affect the rest of the site?

Comment: Will your script get included onto other pages with the old jQuery?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/. They even have an example of using two different versions of jQuery. This isn't recommended though.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="log">
  <h3>Before $.noConflict(true)</h3>
</div>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.2.js"></script>

<script>
var $log = $( "#log" );

$log.append( "2nd loaded jQuery version ($): " + $.fn.jquery + "<br>" );

/*
Restore globally scoped jQuery variables to the first version loaded
(the newer version)
*/
jq162 = jQuery.noConflict(true);

$log.append( "<h3>After $.noConflict(true)</h3>" );
$log.append( "1st loaded jQuery version ($): " + $.fn.jquery + "<br>" );
$log.append( "2nd loaded jQuery version (jq162): " + jq162.fn.jquery + "<br>" );
</script>

</body>
</html>
```